# Generic Object with shared extends in Java

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I'm not sure this is possible but I'm trying to declare an `Object` that will act as a `Class`, `Method` or `Field` (mainly just to call `getAnnotation()`).
I thought of trying `Object<? extends AnnotatedElement>` as they all share that implementation but `Object` is not a generic type.
Is this possible and if not what would be a better approach (besides separate objects for each)?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, maybe because I'm confusing `Object` class with your `Object` implementation, especially in `Object<? extends AnnotatedElement>`. Please show some code of what have you tried to help you better.

Comment: Why not just create a class that extends `AnnotatedElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare as AnnotatedElement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to do too much here, just declare your object as `AnnotatedElement`.

As compelling as it is to use generics as often as possible, we should never forget about the simple, basic constructs of OO. The best way to keep focused is whenever you come up with a construct that looks too complicated compared to what it's doing, just ask yourself the question "Am I using the right tool here?"